# Turning Trees into 1-dimensional curves

Tags: co.combinatorics

In the theory of Young diagrams, it's a common move to turn the young diagram 45 degrees and consider it's profile as a function.  [ Note for editors: it would be nice to find an image of this... ]

Are there ways to build 1-d (probably piecewise linear) curves from trees or from binary trees or ternary trees?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the tree is rooted and planar (that is, children at each vertex are linearly ordered), you can construct its contour function. See, for example, http://www.math.ens.fr/~legall/Rio-lectures.pdf (see p.2).